# How to use AIML <oob> tag

Tags: tags, aiml

I am new in using `<oob>` tag, I am using pandora-bot for chat bot.
I have used many aiml tags and completed my work. Please guide how to use oob tag in aiml so that its response can be implemented in android programming.

Please feel free to ask question if any thing is unclear.
oob tag is responding but not opening search or dialing call.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static String recursEval(Node node, ParseState ps) {
    LOG.info("AIMLProcessor.recursEval(node: " + node + ", ps: " + ps + ")");
    try {
    LOG.info("in AIMLProcessor.recursEval(), node string: " + DomUtils.nodeToString(node));
    String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    LOG.info("in AIMLProcessor.recursEval(), nodeName: " + nodeName);
    LOG.info("in AIMLProcessor.recursEval(), node.getNodeValue(): " + node.getNodeValue());
    if (nodeName.equals("#text")) return node.getNodeValue();
    else if (nodeName.equals("#comment")) {
        LOG.info("in AIMLProcessor.recursEval(), comment = "+node.getTextContent());
        return "";
    }
    else if (nodeName.equals("template"))
        return evalTagContent(node, ps, null);
    else if (nodeName.equals("random"))
        return random(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("condition"))
        return loopCondition(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("srai"))
        return srai(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("sr"))
          return respond(ps.starBindings.inputStars.star(0), ps.that, ps.topic, ps.chatSession, sraiCount);
    else if (nodeName.equals("sraix"))
        return sraix(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("set"))
        return set(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("get"))
        return get(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("map"))  // AIML 2.0 -- see also <set> in pattern
        return map(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("bot"))
        return bot(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("id"))
        return id(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("size"))
        return size(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("vocabulary")) // AIML 2.0
        return vocabulary(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("program"))
        return program(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("date"))
        return date(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("interval"))
        return interval(node, ps);
    //else if (nodeName.equals("gossip"))       // removed from AIML 2.0
    //    return gossip(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("think"))
        return think(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("system"))
        return system(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("explode"))
        return explode(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("normalize"))
        return normalize(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("denormalize"))
        return denormalize(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("uppercase"))
        return uppercase(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("lowercase"))
        return lowercase(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("formal"))
        return formal(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("sentence"))
        return sentence(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("person"))
        return person(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("person2"))
        return person2(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("gender"))
        return gender(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("star"))
        return inputStar(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("thatstar"))
        return thatStar(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("topicstar"))
        return topicStar(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("that"))
        return that(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("input"))
        return input(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("request"))
        return request(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("response"))
        return response(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("learn") || nodeName.equals("learnf"))
        return learn(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("addtriple"))
        return addTriple(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("deletetriple"))
        return deleteTriple(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("javascript"))
        return javascript(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("select"))
        return select(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("uniq"))
        return uniq(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("first"))
        return first(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("rest"))
        return rest(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("resetlearnf"))
        return resetlearnf(node, ps);
    else if (nodeName.equals("resetlearn"))
        return resetlearn(node, ps);
    else if (extension != null && extension.extensionTagSet().contains(nodeName)) return extension.recursEval(node, ps) ;
    else return (genericXML(node, ps));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

You would find a method like this one in program ab in AIMLProcessor class there you have to add the implementation of oob tags . this is the method which parses the response from aiml files based on what tags found in the response it call the necessary funtion